# How to send request each second to server using Observer?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

Just wrap this code into timer?

```
this.requestMethods.CallNotaryRequest(data).subscribe((response: ICallNotaryResponse) => {
    this.requestMethods.CallNotaryRequest();// Call again after 1 second
});
```

Or there is another approach?

I need to execute the same request only when I got response from previous, after 1 second

I tried this way:

```
Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(i => {
  this.askToReadyRecordVideo().subscribe(res => {
  });
});

private askToReadyRecordVideo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.requestMethods.askToReadyRecordVideo({});
}
```

But there is problem when server returns an error , it still sends requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Observable.interval(3000)
    // the error from inner stream(inside `switchMap`) will propagate to outer stream. 
    // Outer stream will complete.
    .pipe(switchMap(()=>this.askToReadyRecordVideo()))
    .subscribe(console.log);

private askToReadyRecordVideo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.requestMethods.askToReadyRecordVideo({});
}
```